# Project fails to build with error "does not reference '". NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" framework'" after restore

Tags: c++, .net, msbuild, nuget, .net-4.7.2

I am trying to create a nuget package using MSBuild and am running into problems after I restore.

This error occurs after I do `msbuild <solution> "/t:<project>" /t:restore /p:Configuration=Release`. To be clear, that command executes successfully, no errors; however, if I try to clean, build, restore or pack following that command is when I get the following error. (note that **<path-to-repo>**, **<solution>** and **<project>** are substitutions)

```
Build FAILED.

"C:\Users\<path-to-repo>\build\win32\<solution>.sln" (<project>;restore target) (1) ->
"C:\Users\<path-to-repo>\extras\<project>\<project>.vcxproj.metaproj" (default target) (2) ->
"C:\Users\<path-to-repo>\extras\<project>\<project>.vcxproj" (default target) (4) ->
(ResolveNuGetPackageAssets target) ->
  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\17.0\Microsoft.NuGet.targets(198,5): error : Your project does not reference ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" framework. Add a reference to ".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" in the "TargetFrameworks" property of your project file and then re-run NuGet restore. [C:\Users\<path-to-repo>\extras\<project>\<project>.vcxproj]
```

The project restores and builds correctly before I add the following section to the .vcxproj file (which I believe is necessary in order to pack the project as a nuget package).

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack">
    <Version>6.4.0</Version>
    <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
  </PackageReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

Simply adding that, and running restore and then clean/restore/build/pack afterwards all fail with the error.

This section is present in the project file which seems to correctly reference the target framework.

```
<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
  ...
  <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

I've cleaned out all the bin/obj and other untracked files at the root of the repo with `git clean -xdf` as that was a very popular suggestion (the only change in the repo is the package reference above added to the project file); I am unaware of any files I would need to clean outside of the repo?

Thanks in advance for any help! Questions about this error seem to be asked a lot for different scenarios, seems like they might need better error messages.

Comment: I am using `MSBuild version 17.3.1+2badb37d1 for .NET Framework`

Comment: Did you try `nuget pack yourProject.csproj`?